# windows 8 modal progress dialogue (like messagebox with own content and buttons...)

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to start async operation in c# metro application and I would like to show modal dialogue with ProgressRing.

Is there any easy way howto do it? Or any best practises howto do this?

Comment: My answer in another question talks about how I create a modal dialog: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14441992/1822514  It is not a "step-by-step" solution and may not totally answer your question.

Comment: Callisto also has a dialog class, although I have not used it: https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/wiki/CustomDialog

Answer (score 1):

The modal dialog box class in WinRT is [MessageDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx).  Here are the [best practices for using dialogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh738363).

There is a code sample for message dialogs at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Message-dialog-sample-00c928f5.