# How do I show a page modally in a universal Windows Runtime 8.1 app?

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm making a universal Windows Runtime 8.1 version of our app, originally an iOS app.  I'm trying to find out how to display a page modally in the app.

In iOS, I'd use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`, but I can't find an equivalent in WinRT.  I've seen the [task mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263247.aspx) which only mentions navigation frames (they're the equivalent of using `pushViewController:`, which isn't what I want) and I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372271/how-to-show-a-full-screen-modal-contentdialog-in-windows-phone-8-1) which talks about a `ContentDialog` class, but that's only available for phone apps, not universal ones.

How do I show a page modally in a *universal* app?

Comment: What does it mean to show a page modally? Do you want to show a modal popup?

Comment: I have a Page, and I want to show it on the screen, full-screen until I'm finished with it; then I want to go back to the screen I was on in the exact state it was in before I left it.

Comment: I haven't done much with Unversal Apps, so the following may or may not apply in your situation - I did this for Windows Store Apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409184/how-to-disable-a-grid-panel-in-xaml-metro-app